# How to use non final variable in Java 8 Lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, final

How can I use non-final variable in Java 8 lambda. It throws compilation error saying 'Local variable date defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final'

I actually want to achieve the following

```
public Integer getTotal(Date date1, Date date2) {
    if(date2 == null || a few more conditions) {
        date2 = someOtherDate;
    }
    return someList.stream().filter(filter based on date1 and date2).map(Mapping Function).reduce(Addition);
}
```

How do I achieve this? It throws comilation error for date2.
Thanks,

Comment: By the way, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). You may be interested in the `Period` and `Duration` classes.

Answer (score 16):

Use another variable that you can initiate once.

```
final Date tmpDate;
if(date2 == null || a few more conditions) {
    tmpDate = someOtherDate;
} else {
    tmpDate = date2;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This should be helpful.

```
public Long getTotal(Date date1, Date date2) {
    final AtomicReference<Date> date3 = new AtomicReference<>();
    if(date2 == null ) {
        date3.getAndSet(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }
    return someList.stream().filter(x -> date1.equals(date3.get())).count();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just get the param date2 outside and then calling the method getTotal, just like this below:

```
Date date1;
Date date2;

if(date2 == null || a few more conditions) {
   date2 = someOtherDate;
}

getTotal(date1, date2)


public Integer getTotal(Date date1, Date date2) {
    return someList.stream().filter(filter based on date1 and date2).map(Mapping Function).reduce(Addition);
}
```

Comment: What if the method is called from outside the class?

Comment: Create a another method to combine the two function, one is getting the result of param date2, another one is getting the final result by param date1 and date2. And we can call the new method from outside class

Answer (score 0):

Just add a line like

```
Date date3 = date2; // date3 is effectively final in Java 8. Add 'final' keyword in Java 7.
```

right before your lambda and use `date3` in place of `date2`.

Answer (score 0):

*use a* Date-array *for the use in the lambda*

```
public Integer getTotal(Date date1, Date date2) {
  Date[] date = {date2 == null || a few more conditions ? someOtherDate : date2};
  return someList.stream().filter(filter based on date[0]).map(Mapping Function).reduce(Addition);
}
```

In contrast to a non-array solution, `date[0]` could even be changed within a non-parallel stream.