# How do I log non-final variables using a lazily evaluated expression?

Tags: java, logging

I would like to create a log message which contains the values of at least one local variable. To benefit form lazy evaluation I would like to pass a `Supplier<String>` to the logging frame work.

```
private void  doSomething(Object a, Object b){
   var myLocalVar = deriveValFrom(a);
   if (null == myLocalVar){
       myLocalVar = deriveValFrom(b);
   }
   LOG.debug(() -> String.format("settled on value %s", myLocalVar));
}
```

The code above does not compile, since `myLocalVar` is neither final nor effectively final.

**current ideas**
As the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307541/how-to-use-non-final-variable-in-java-8-lambdas) show, I might define a temp variable and thus bloat the code.

Otherwise I could implement a private method like

```
private void logToDebug(String formatStr, Object p0, Objects... objs){
   LOG.debug(()->String.format(formatStr, p0, objs));
}
```

Which makes the compiler stop complaining but adds 'off-topic' code to the class.

**actual Q**
Is there a better way to achieve lazy evaluation and concise code?

**relevant info**
While logging is done under the hood by log4j I have to work through a custom facade which I may extend (for instance with the `debug(String formatStr, p0, ...)`-Methods) but I would like to keep the extension to a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd split logic into two methods:

```
private void doSomething(Object a, Object b){
    final var myLocalVar = deriveValFrom(a);
    if (myLocalVar != null)
        return myLocalVar;
    return deriveValFrom(b);
}

private void doSomethingAndLog(Object a, Object b){
    final var myLocalVar = doSomething(a, b);
    LOG.debug(() -> String.format("settled on value %s", myLocalVar));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what part of the exection you want to be lazy.
A final constant would normally use an assignless expression. Optional is very suitable for that.

But you can do all in the log call.

```
private void  doSomething(Object a, Object b) {
   final var myLocalVar = Optional.ofNullable(deriveValFrom(a))
                                  .orElseGet(() -> deriveValFrom(b)));
   LOG.debug(() -> "settled on value %s".formatted(
       Optional.ofNullable(deriveValFrom(a))
               .orElseGet(() -> deriveValFrom(b)));
}
```